# Docker containers unable to resolve DNS on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, devops, centos7

I'm migrating to a new VPS on hostgator, and it comes with CentOS and WHM+CPanel preinstalled.

After installing docker, and trying to run a few containers, i'm having a weird issue, and i really don't know the cause.

The containers can ping to ips, but not domains, giving me a "bad address".

After a whole day researching and trying stuff like forcing a dns on the daemon.json file, looking for a firewall to disable (i don't have firewall-cmd installed, only iptables, and even with it stopped, the problem continues), and nothing resulted in the dns working.

My host resolv.conf:

`search hostgator_br.com nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4`

and docker is generating this resolv:

`search hostgator_br.com nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Any tips on what else to try?

**UPDATE**

After trying to narrow down the issue, i've verified that if i run containers using --network host, the dns works fine, so the problem is probably on the docker0 bridge created by docker during the installation.

I've already tried to force docker to recreate the interface as suggested somewhere, and still no luck solving this issue.

This is the network as displayed by docker

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "b4c3ccb12d6f1d2c93826747d484d5ca1da3caee55de542186f3862daca25421",
        "Created": "2023-06-02T20:23:11.559417943-03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "25a8ec4b8adf762bbc4528651ba5dfe6a1841955f25f79518707366c12c07158": {
                "Name": "captain-certbot.1.zu5mlt2qeqp7foob4up1m14gk",
                "EndpointID": "15829be714641f43bc2b0b6cf0a9b3537fb2d3c01d93ab2a27f447296008cc1d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**UPDATE 2**

If i disable iptables, everything works perfectly, so it's probably some rule preventing dns resolution, but i have no idea on what rule is, and how to fix it.

This is the result of

> iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  bl16-114-196.dsl.telepac.pt  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  wz.hostgator.com.br  anywhere             /* allow Wizard/Eigsh */
ACCEPT     all  --  financeiro.hostgator.com.br  anywhere             /* allow Painel */
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Inbound Allow lo */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:ndmps:65534
tcpchk     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
udpchk     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
input_custom  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: up to 2/sec burst 10 mode srcip
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level error prefix "ICMP_DROP "
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp fragmentation-needed
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp port-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp host-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmptype 30
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  173.245.48.0/20      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.21.244.0/22      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.22.200.0/22      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  103.31.4.0/22        anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  141.101.64.0/18      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  108.162.192.0/18     anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  190.93.240.0/20      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  188.114.96.0/20      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  197.234.240.0/22     anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  198.41.128.0/17      anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  162.158.0.0/15       anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  104.16.0.0/13        anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  104.24.0.0/14        anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  172.64.0.0/13        anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  vps-10665803.pjinformatica.org  anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  198-1-121-202.unifiedlayer.com  anywhere             multiport dports ssh,http
ACCEPT     icmp --  198-1-121-202.unifiedlayer.com  anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  54.e2.adb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  anywhere             multiport dports ssh,http
ACCEPT     icmp --  54.e2.adb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  32.e0.acb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  anywhere             multiport dports ssh,http
ACCEPT     icmp --  32.e0.acb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:26
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:infowave
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:radsec
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sunclustergeo
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:gnunet
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:eli
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sep
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:EtherNet/IP-1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:nbx-ser
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:nbx-dir
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     udp  --  dns.google           anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  dns.google           anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  dns.google           anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  dns.google           anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:22022
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:22022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:hbci
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:hbci
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "LOG_INPUT: "
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
tcpchk     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
udpchk     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Outbound allow lo */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:323 /* chronyd */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner GID match mailman
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner GID match mail
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports smtp,urd,submission owner UID match root
tcpchk     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
udpchk     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            
output_custom  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             198-1-121-202.unifiedlayer.com  icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             54.e2.adb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             32.e0.acb8.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:saphostctrls
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:saphostctrls
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:30000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ndmps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:nicname
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:nicname
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:rsync
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match root
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway07.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway03.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway04.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway05.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway06.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway09.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway10.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway11.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway12.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway13.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway14.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway15.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway16.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway02.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway01.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             gateway08.websitewelcome.com  tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp owner UID match mailnull
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! owner UID match root multiport dports smtp,urd,submission limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level notice prefix "OUTBOUND-SMTP : "
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain ! owner UID match nobody
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ! owner UID match nobody
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             dns.google           udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             dns.google           tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             dns.google           udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             dns.google           tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain owner UID match nobody limit: avg 20/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain owner UID match nobody limit: avg 20/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:gnunet
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:eli
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sep
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:time
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:sms-chat
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:22022
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:26
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:infowave
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:radsec
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:sunclustergeo
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:gnunet
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:eli
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:sep
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:EtherNet/IP-1
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:nbx-ser
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:nbx-dir
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8           tcp dpt:50905
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:hbci
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:hbci
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:webcache
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "LOG_OUTPUT: "
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp reject-with tcp-reset
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain icmpchk (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain input_custom (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain output_custom (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ssh (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  supra.websitewelcome.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  ce.2f.1732.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  wizard-backup.hostgator.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  216-106-185-169.ds1-static.mia1.net.ststelecom.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  12.96.160.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  216.19.0.0/24        anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  162-241-18-61.unifiedlayer.com  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  162-214-41-61.unifiedlayer.com  anywhere            
           tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 limit: avg 10/min burst 5 LOG level notice prefix "SSH-ATTACK : "
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255 reject-with tcp-reset
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain tcpchk (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain udpchk (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Hi there. Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem here and struggling for more than 4 days on it.